# Always Searching for default action method in all controller

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4, routes

I am having following route in my application : -

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "MyAction", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );
```

Now I added another controller named "ErrorController" Where I am having Index action method. but it is throwing error -

```
"A public action method 'MyAction' was not found on controller 'MyApplication.Controllers.ErrorController'."
```

What I am missing here?

Comment: 1. Do you have a MyActionController? 2. Are you able to view the /error page?

Comment: nope i don't have "MyActionController" and also I am not able to view error page because of the error mentioned above..... I am trying to redirect to error page from "Application_Error" event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you write the URL `http://YourDomain/Error`, your routing rules call the `MyAction` action of the `ErrorController`.

If you want to call the `Index` action, the URL must be:

```
http://YourDomain/Error/Index
```

**EDIT**

Add this rule **before** yours:

```
 routes.MapRoute(
    "Error",
    "Error/{action}/{id}", 
     new { controller = "Error", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
```

Comment: Is there any other way of doing that.....in this case "/Index" is visible in the URL, ideally it should not.

Comment: In your routing rule, in place of `action = "MyAction"`, write `action = "Index"`

Comment: that will overwrite the Home controllers default action method.....how about adding another route which will take the "Index" as the default controller other then "Home" controller....is it possible?